# Why won't my C long store a number bigger than a regular Int?

Tags: c, long-integer

For some reason I cannot get the number 4294967296, or any bigger to be stored in a long.
On the second run through the loop the change variable goes to 0 after being multiplied despite being a long.

```
unsigned long interleave(unsigned int i1, unsigned int i2) {
    long int out = 0l;
    unsigned long r1;
    unsigned long r2;
    unsigned long change;
    change = 1l;
    unsigned long store;
    unsigned long bitSize = 256l;
    printf("%010x + %010x = ", i1, i2);
    //printf("START CHANGE %016x or %lu\n", change, change);
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        //Get remainder for int 1;
        r1 = (unsigned long)i1 % (unsigned long)bitSize;
        i1 = (unsigned long)i1 / (unsigned long)bitSize;
        //Get remainder for int 2;
        r2 = (unsigned long)i2 % (unsigned long)bitSize;
        i2 = (unsigned long)i2 / (unsigned long)bitSize;
        //printf("GOT %04x and %04x\n", r1, r2);
        store = ((unsigned long)r1 * (unsigned long)bitSize) + (unsigned long)r2;
        store = (unsigned long)store * (unsigned long)change;
        //printf("STORE %016x\n", store);
        change = ((unsigned long)change) * ((unsigned long)bitSize);
        printf("CHANGE AFTER FIRST MULTIPLICATION: %016x or %lu\n", change, change);
        change = ((unsigned long)change) * ((unsigned long)bitSize);
        printf("CHANGE AFTER SECOND MULTIPLICATION: %016x or %lu\n", change, change);
        //printf("OUT: %016x\n", out);
        out += (unsigned long)store;
    }
    printf("%016x", out);

}

int main() {
    interleave((unsigned)4294967295, (unsigned)2999999);
    char* ch;
    scanf("%c%c", ch, ch);
}
```

I have tried switching the datatype to a "long long", or a "long int", or a "long long int". None seems to work. I have now explicitly cast all athematic to "unsigned long" but that also fails. The function is supposed to interleave the two integers on a per byte basis so "c245a1" and "1e67ba" should interleave to "c21e4567a1ba". Instead for some reason when I use a long it can't hold anything that big, neither can a "long long".

Comment: What is `sizeof(long)` on your system?

Comment: Try using `lx` instead of just `x` to print `unsigned long` values.

Comment: @John Serlin What does this     char* ch;
    scanf("%c%c", ch, ch); mean?!

Comment: There are two problems with the `scanf` call:  (1) `ch` is uninitialized, so you're storing into an uninitialized pointer.  That's undefined behavior.  Your program could easily experience a segmentation fault, or worse, from that.  And (2) You're specifying the same variable twice.  What is the point of that `scanf` call?

Comment: Scanf was just to prevent the program from closing before I could read the results. However when I did sizeof(long) it was only 4 bytes, so I switched to long long. It still wasn't working but using "llx" instead of "x" made the printing work. So thank you Barmar and dbush you guys solved my problem.

Comment: why are you needlessly casting things to the very types that they are?  why are you casting ints to longs for what then amounts to integer division where the long wont help you anyway especially since you are storing it back into an int.    not really clear what you are doing.  Why can't you produce a Minimal Reproducible Example of this without all the extra nonsense to demonstrate your actual issue?  What in the world do you mean be interleave? And you don't even return from your function.

Comment: "*prevent the program from closing before I could read the results*" is indicative of a poorly configured environment. Presumably you are executing this program, and it is running via something like Windows CMD.EXE which opens a window on startup, and closes the window on exit. Specifically for this case, what you need is the `cmd /k` switch, or similar. Ideally, you need a properly configured IDE or terminal emulator. Barring any of that, to avoid *undefined behaviour*, replace the flawed `scanf` call with a simple `getchar()` until you read your C textbook's chapter on pointers.

Comment: Perhaps include `<stdint.h>` and use `uintXX_t` to ensure your types have the size you expect.

Comment: `long int` does not necessarily have a range including 4294967296, but `long long int` must.

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned long interleave(unsigned int i1, unsigned int i2) {
    unsigned long long int out = 0l;
    unsigned long long int r1;
    unsigned long long int r2;
    unsigned long long int change;
    change = 1ll;
    unsigned long long store;
    unsigned long long bitSize = 256l;
    printf("%08x + %08x = ", i1, i2);
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        //Get remainder for int 1;
        r1 = (unsigned long long)i1 % (unsigned long long)bitSize;
        i1 = (unsigned long long)i1 / (unsigned long long)bitSize;
        //Get remainder for int 2;
        r2 = (unsigned long long)i2 % (unsigned long long)bitSize;
        i2 = (unsigned long long)i2 / (unsigned long long)bitSize;
        store = ((unsigned long long)r1 * (unsigned long long)bitSize) + (unsigned long long)r2;
        store = (unsigned long long)store * (unsigned long long)change;
        change = ((unsigned long long)change) * ((unsigned long long)bitSize);
        change = ((unsigned long long)change) * ((unsigned long long)bitSize);
        out += (unsigned long long)store;
    }
    printf("%016llx", out);
    return out;
}
```

Thank you to Barmar and dbush. It turns out the longs on my system were the same size as ints, I needed to change it to a Long Long as Barmar suggested. However I didn't realize that had solved the problem because I needed to use "llx" instead of "x" in the printf in order to see the rest of the numbers as dbush suggested. If anyone else is having this sort of issue just change your long to a long long and see if that fixes it, also check for correct printing.

Comment: In future, use a debugger to inspect values rather than relying on printf where you have to get that code right too.  That is do not rely on _your_ code to debug _your_ code.  Also, your compiler may have support for format specifier checking - check the warning options.  For example `-Wformat` in GCC

Answer (score 1):

C standard only specifies minimum values required by the type and does not guarantee that `long` will be larger than `int`

```
(absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
— number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
CHAR_BIT 8
— minimum value for an object of type signed char
SCHAR_MIN -127 // −(2 7 − 1)
— maximum value for an object of type signed char
SCHAR_MAX +127 // 2 7 − 1
— maximum value for an object of type unsigned char
UCHAR_MAX 255 // 2 8 − 1
— minimum value for an object of type char
CHAR_MIN see below
— maximum value for an object of type char
CHAR_MAX see below
— maximum number of bytes in a multibyte character, for any supported locale
MB_LEN_MAX 1
— minimum value for an object of type short int
SHRT_MIN -32767 // −(2 15 − 1)
— maximum value for an object of type short int
SHRT_MAX +32767 // 2 15 − 1
— maximum value for an object of type unsigned short int
USHRT_MAX 65535 // 2 16 − 1
— minimum value for an object of type int
INT_MIN -32767 // −(2 15 − 1)
— maximum value for an object of type int
INT_MAX +32767 // 2 15 − 1
— maximum value for an object of type unsigned int
UINT_MAX 65535 // 2 16 − 1
— minimum value for an object of type long int
LONG_MIN -2147483647 // −(2 31 − 1)
— maximum value for an object of type long int
LONG_MAX +2147483647 // 231 − 1
— maximum value for an object of type unsigned long int
ULONG_MAX 4294967295 // 2 32 − 1
— minimum value for an object of type long long int
LLONG_MIN -9223372036854775807 // −(2 63 − 1)
— maximum value for an object of type long long int
LLONG_MAX +9223372036854775807 // 2 63 − 1
— maximum value for an object of type unsigned long long int
ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615 // 2 64 − 1
```